# Ruby and RVM version not showing correctly

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

When I run `ruby -v` from my ubuntu 12.04 terminal then I get ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [i686-linux]. But when I specify rvm to use ruby 2.1.1 by this command `rvm use 2.1.1` I get this output -->  `

```
tamim@tamim-K43E:/media/Software/git/regexper$ rvm use ruby 2.1.1p76
ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247'

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

` 
I am new in ruby and never touch it before, just using it to install a software.

```
    tamim@tamim-K43E:/media/Software/git/regexper$ rvm -v
ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247'

rvm 1.25.22 (manual) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

gem version : 2.2.2

Comment: If you're stuck with rvm, that's fine. If you have the option to change, I would recommend [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). All of my ruby version woes went away after rbenv.

Comment: What is the output of rvm list?

Comment: this is rvm list output -->  rvm list
ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247'

rvm rubies


# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.

Comment: hav u done this "change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell" ..open terminal, edit --> profile preferences --> title and command --> select run command as login shell

Answer (score 0):

Only following should work:

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1
```

Comment: 'rvm use ruby 2.1.1
ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247'

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
'
Same as before.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "-" in between, It should be `rvm use ruby-2.1.1`, edited the answer as well.